# instantaneously sync time via NTP after large offset on win10

Tags: windows-10, sync, time, ntp

One of my Win10 machines has a large time offset, in the order to weeks (its a VM that gets unpaused on request).

In the age of short-lived SSL certificates, it is crucial for many (web-based) operations to have correct time set. For precision reasons (and because I don't want to be bothered to "manually" remember the actual time) I'd like to use NTP.

Unfortunately, because the time offset is so large, when synching to an NTP server the time is either adjusted *very* slowly or discarded altogether, (making the time practically unusable until the next reboot).

So I thought about doing something like:

- set the time manually to something approximately the wall-clock time
- enable automatic time synchronization (NTP), to do the final adjustments

Unfortunately, the system is playing tricks on me, as this is what's actually happening:

- I unpause the machine; it has a time of e.g. `2018-04-30 13:17`
- I login, right-click the clock, select "change time and date"
- I switch **off** the `automatic time synchronisation` (as it was enabled in the paused machine)
- I click on `Change time/date`
- I set the date to approx the current date, e.g. `2018-06-13 10:35`
- I close the window via the `Apply` button, and see how the (almost) correct is displayed in the task-bar
- I switch **on** the `automatic time synchronisation` again, to get the minutes and seconds right
- the spinning wheel is displayed for a few seconds and then...
- the time is restored to the **old** *wrong* value of `2018-04-30 13:17`!

What is going on here?

After a *couple of minutes* the time will eventually synchronize to the NTP server (it's working fine).

But how can I sync to the NTP-server *instantaneously*?
I really don't want to wait a couple of minutes to be able to use the machine,
as the machine's sole purpose is to provide a clean environment to try out small things **quickly**.

Comment: Instead of pausing/unpausing just let it run continuously or shut it down while not needed? As for your timing issue it might be related to the machines actual clock not yet being up to date and you might want to check whenever calling `w32tm` directly allows you to "instantaneously" get the correct time.

Comment: @Seth shutting down or continuously running are not an option (i need a *clean* environment *instantaneously*; think [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)); as for using `w32tm` for setting the time, I have basically the same problem (but hoped to attract more answers in a GUI-only question :-): as soon as i issue a `net start w32time`, the time gets reset to the old/wrong value. finally I don't know what you mean with "the machines actual clock".

Comment: Why would you start it instead of actually telling it to run a sync? And with the machines actual clock I'm talking about the machines actual clock that's saved in the BIOS.

Comment: Just doing a plain sync was refused because the time difference is too big (even after setting `MaxPosPhaseCorrection` and `MaxNedPhaseCorrection` to `0xFFFFFFFF`]).

Comment: Could you post the actual error message? Doing a time travel to 1999 and running `w32tm /resync` took mere seconds.